# Model for listing Items

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to list names from database based on the alias ID

```
public class Name
{
    int _nameID,_aliasID;
    string _nameNA;
}



 public List<Name> Names(int aliasID)
    {
        List<Name> nm = new List<Name>();
        using (DatabaseCommaned cmd=new DatabaseCommaned("SELECT NA FROM dbo.tName WHERE AliasID="+aliasID+""))
            {
                try
                {
                    SqlDataReader rdr = new SqlDataReader();
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        Name n = new Name();
                        n.nameNA=(string)rdr["NA"];

                        Add nm(n);                             
                    }

                }

            }

        return nm;
    }
```

These are my classes. I cant take this from reader. How it possible. putting underscore in the variable, make difficult. Is this right way . Or please tell me the other ways.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to execute the command first cmd.ExecuteReader().

And then read from the reader.

```
using (SqlDataReader reader cmd.ExecuteReader()){
   // read the information here
}
```

if you are talking about the class definition. the following should be the correct one.

```
public class Name
{
    public int NameID {get;set;}
    public int AliasID {get;set;}
    public string NameNA {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: i do it. but didnot get the variables from name class

Comment: i didn't get that n.variable name.can u tell what is the problem.

Comment: have you tried to debug that and see if the value is actually getting return? e.g. rdr["NA"] is actually there? I am not sure what do you mean by you don't get that n.variable name. Is the could you put here in the class definition correct for Name?? you should put the field as public if you want to set the value.

Comment: If you are having problem accessing the underscore XXXX field that is because it is set to private by default. you'd better use public property to do that. take a look at this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx